# SCRIPT to change default search engine (with or without having to install browser addon)

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, search-engine, nsis

**Goal :** Change FF, IE, Chrome, Safari, Default search engine, Homepage and url searchbar

**Tools & Scripts :** I would like to have a link on the page, that would suggest to make the changes described above. The user has to optin (i don't want aggressive silent install). Ideally without installing a browser addon (but not sure its possible without)

**Limitations :**

- I'm aware it's different methods for each browser, but even if you
  have the solution for one, it would be great.
- I'm also aware that the easiest way is to go through the registry
  using a broswer extension, yet i didn't find the solution for each
  browser, links would be much appreciated.
- I was suggested also to make these changes through a NSIS installer and i successfully did it, but i would like to know how to do it simply within the broswer extension or ideally from within the page (with a JS or something else).

Thanks a lot in advance, i'm no expert so don't hesitate to go into details as i'm willing to explore all solutions.

PS : i've looked extensively around and there was a lot of topics about manually make these changes, or with an extension for a specific browser, but none about a direct link making these changes.

**UPDATE1:**

**I'm also looking for a complete article about how to change default search engine and homepage WITH an extension for FF, Chrome, IE and Safari. Thanks a lot**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For IE:**

You just need to edit the registry

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER "Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main" "Start Page" 
HKEY_CURRENT_USER "Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main" "Default_Search_URL"
HKEY_CURRENT_USER "Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main" "Default_Page_URL" "http://abc.com/"
HKEY_CURRENT_USER "Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\SearchScopes\YourSearchEngineName" "DisplayName" "YourSearchEngineName"
HKEY_CURRENT_USER "Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\SearchScopes\YourSearchEngineName" "URL" "YourSearchEngineUrl"
HKEY_CURRENT_USER "Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\SearchScopes" "DefaultScope" "YourSearchEngineName"
```

**For chrome:**

Find this file:

```
"$LOCALAPPDATA\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences"
```

Use [nsJson plugin](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/File%3aNsJSON.zip) to edit its "homepage" attribute.

For changing the url search bar (default search) , you need to find some way to edit the sqlite database:

```
"$LOCALAPPDATA\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Web Data
```

In this there is a keywords table where you have to add your search engine. And then update it in the meta table of same databse.

**For Firefox:**

Find this file:

```
 $APPDATA\Mozilla\Profiles\default_profile\prefs.js
```

Its a javascript file, you can edit its attributes to change the home page and default search.

Comment: If you edit IE's registry key like this, Defender can treat you as malware, and you'll find that the registry keys are reverted as they're protected by a hash.

Comment: @EricLaw So what would you suggest then ?

Comment: Any real world sample using IE 11 ?

Comment: How about Edge?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some info on Chrome and Firefox [on this page](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=2158301), however for IE there seems to be only Add-On way of changing the search engine. Good luck!

Comment: it's very interesting, but it seems to require Greasemonkey extension doesn't it ? How would you use it without greasemonkey scripts ?

Comment: It seems so. I'm guessing that in order to try out a script without the Greasemonkey extension you might need to look a little bit deeper into the way Chrome/Firefox is built. Or you can take a look into [OpenSearch](http://blog.unto.net/add-opensearch-to-your-site-in-five-minutes.html), which seems to give the option of customizing the browser's search box. In any case, Googling around should help more

Comment: Also, you can check out WebKit, which is used by Chrome. Some info about it [is here](http://hiddencodes.wordpress.com/2012/01/06/webkitchrome-and-search-engine-provider/).

Comment: Thanks Thara for this great link, very useful.
Do you have the same kind of ressource but based on regedits that could be bundled with NSIS installer ?